# Can't use the REPLACE function in netbean's JavaDB?

Tags: sql, derby

Firstly, I'm new to SQL - not so new to Java anymore.

Secondly, I'm using NetBeans 8.2 with JavaDB and when I'm trying to run a SQL query, such as:

```
SELECT Replace(BOOKNAME, ' ', '') from BOOKINFO;
```

and try to execute the commend, the console displays an error, namely:

> [Exception, Error code 30,000, SQLState 42Y03] 'REPLACE' is not recognized as a function or procedure.

Any ideas on what I can do? Do you see something wrong with my query code?

Comment: which dbms are you using? is it DB2?

Comment: Using SQL Server

Comment: "JavaDB" is the name of the Apache Derby open source database.  SQL Server is a Microsoft product.

Comment: I am studying, so some things are not well understood, thanks.

Comment: so the question is no longer needed ? if so please close it or update it.